# PHP Namespace oddity folders ending with "t","s","n"

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, php-5.6

I am having an intersting issue where if one of the folders in the namespace ends in a "t", "s", or "n" then has a subfolder after it then it wont parse.

EX:

```
namespace DDM\Components\Widget\List;
```

This causes: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in <...filepath...>`

Same happens for folder ending with the other 2 letters previously mentioned.

I am on a windows system but the files are being served from a Debian (jessie) box, running PHP Version 5.6.27-0+deb8u1 through nginx and PHP-FPM

**Update**

If I try prefixing the entire namespace with a `\` then phpstorm no longer recognizes it as a syntax error but the php compiler still gives the same error as above.

**Any "L" name subfolder has this result**

As pointed out by Jay `List` is a PHP reserved word, however using any "L" folder name results in a different error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined constant 'DDM\Components\Widget\Lists'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `List` is a reserved keyword and reserved keywords are not allowed, even in namespaces.

[PHP Reserved Keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Comment: Any word beging with L seems to give the same results `...Widget\Lothername;`

Comment: @Chausser Namespaces are only supported in  `PHP 5.3+`. Is your PHP version correct?

Comment: im running php 5.6

Comment: I updated the question, i actually get a different error when using a different "L" word folder `Fatal error: Undefined constant 'DDM\Components\Widget\Lists' `

Comment: I had to remove the leading backslash and that solved the problem but `List` being a reserved word does seem to be the main issue. Thanks